# /usr/bin/env: ruby2.1: Permission denied

Tags: ruby, linux

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": true,
  "cmd": "cd /home/username && bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production",
  "delta": "0:00:00.376426",
  "end": "2022-08-03 12:33:57.663786",
  "failed": true,
  "rc": 126,
  "start": "2022-08-03 12:33:57.287360",
  "stderr": "Your RubyGems version (2.7.10) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`\n/usr/bin/env: ruby2.1: Permission denied",
  "stderr_lines": [
    "Your RubyGems version (2.7.10) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`",
    "/usr/bin/env: ruby2.1: Permission denied"
  ],
  "stdout": "",
  "stdout_lines": []
}
```

What am I missing here?

[Later edit]
After going back and forth with this, installing I was able to fix it by running:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.3 /usr/bin/ruby2.1
```

Comment: Seems that you are missing executable permissions. Set ```chmod +x``` on your ```/usr/bin/env ruby2.1``` command output file

Comment: but I don't have ruby2.1, I have ruby2.3

Comment: that might be an separate ruby installation, which calls ruby2.1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby2.3 /usr/bin/ruby2.1
```